# Usage of "in places"

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases, phrase-choice

A question about "in places":

> [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/place_1)
>   1. The paint was peeling off the wall ***in places***.
>   2. The paint was peeling off the wall ***in some places***.
>   3. The paint was peeling off the wall.

(I added sentences 2 & 3.)
How are these three sentences different?
What does "in places" mean relative to "in some places"?

Answer (score 2):

Only considering this particular sentence, the meaning is exactly the same, because the paint won't come off as a complete layer due to the nature of paint on a wall.

But consider the following sentence:

- `The road was wet.` => meaning that the whole road was wet of rain.
- `The road was wet in places.` => meaning that the road was mostly dry, but some people emptied their buckets of washing water onto the road, making it wet in places.

Or consider the following context:

- `The house wasn't renovated for fifty years, and the paint was peeling off the wall.` => most of the paint peeled off during the last 50 years.
- `The house wasn't renovated for fifty years, and the paint was peeling off the wall in some places.` -> most of the paint stayed on, despite the fact that it was 50 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context they have basically the same meaning.

In the case of using "in some places", I would expect some more info., such as:

> 2) The paint was peeling off the wall **in some places** where the wall got wet.
>   The paint was peeling off the wall **in some places**, but was OK in other places.

Basically you're further defining *some*.

Comment: How would the meaning of sentence 1 change if "in places" is deleted?  (I also edited my original question.)

Comment: @meatie In that case is becomes just a general statement of condition. The paint could be peeling in a few places, many places or everywhere.